# Rails link_to how to show blank when null

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my view:

```
 <td><%= link_to product_sale.product.consignor.try(:NAME), { controller: :consignors, action: :edit, ID: product_sale.product.consignor.try(:ID) }, :target => "_blank" %></td>
```

which in product_sale view links to edit consignors for products listed.

Some product doesn't have consignor. When that happens, it shows `/consignors/edit`

How can I show it blank instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say show it blank instead do you mean not show the link? If so, can't you simply just conditionally call the link_to helper:

```
<td><%= product_sale.product.consignor ? (link_to edit_consignor_path(product_sale.product.consignor) ) : '' %></td>
```

As long as your routes are set up correctly you shouldn't need to be specifying the `controller`, `action` and `id` either.

If you want to display something more meaningful to the end user instead of the default link then add an extra parameter before the edit path:

```
<td><%= product_sale.product.consignor ? (link_to product_sale.product.consignor.name, edit_consignor_path(product_sale.product.consignor) ) : '' %></td>
```

and maybe consider setting a variable for readability:

```
<td><% consignor = product_sale.product.consignor %>
<%= consignor ? (link_to consignor.name, edit_consignor_path(consignor) ) : '' %></td>
```

if you aren't interesting in displaying anything other than blank for when no consignor is set then you could replace the tertiary operator with an if statement as suggested by 2called-chaos:

```
<td><% consignor = product_sale.product.consignor %>
<%= link_to consignor.name, edit_consignor_path(consignor) if consignor %></td>
```

Comment: How about `<%= link_to(...) if product_sale.product.consignor %>`?

Comment: @2called-chaos That works too ... only advantage of using tertiary operator, as I have done, is that you could display something other than blank string - e.g.: 'Consigner not assigned'

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your solution shows blank when a product has no consignor, which is correct, but for products with consignor link shown became /consignors/438ae0ab-00ca-4d10-a0e1-8fd4af8d1171/edit. Does that happen because of my routes setup then?

Comment: hmm perhaps ... what is your routes looking like ... rake routes should be producing something like `edit_consignor GET    /consignors/:id/edit(.:format)       consignors#edit` .... that looks like it's using a guid in place of id for whatever reason, or is the :id correct and it's the visual aspect you don't like?

Comment: In my routes I have  match ':controller(/:action(/:ID))', :via => [:get, :post] and if i do rake routes I get   edit_consignor GET /consignors/:id/edit(.:format)     consignors#edit which should be correct then..

Comment: seems so ... are you using a gem to use guid strings instead of integers as id's then? I'm assuming clicking on the link actually does take you to the edit form? To change what is displayed to the end user is easy just add a first parameter to link_to to display what you wish, for example `link_to 'Edit Consignor', edit_consignor_path.......` or something more meaningful if necessary ... e.g. `product_sale.product.consignor.name`

Comment: Ok now it displays everything right. But the link does not work because it takes me to consignors/7640bf86-a56e-4720-8f50-65eda87d432f/edit while before working links were going to consignors/edit/7640bf86-a56e-4720-8f50-65eda87d432f/. I think that's because of match ':controller(/:action(/:ID))', :via => [:get, :post] and that's the reason I was specifying action and id..

Comment: ok then you need to change link_to then to reflect your route: `link_to consignor.name, consignor, {controller: :consignors, action: :edit, ID: consignor.ID }` i guess